# Kotlin jetpack compose desktop в Jar не работает

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Есть проект на Koltin, использую шаблон compose desktop в intellij idea, пытаюсь скомпелировать в Jar через Artifacts выбрав jar -> form modules with dependencies .
В вкладке Bild выбираю bild artifacts и под файлом нажимаю bild.

В консоли появляеться ошибка

```
Kotlin: The provided plugin androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void registerProjectComponents(com.intellij.mock.MockProject, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:671)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:162)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:572)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:192)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:107)
```

Вобще не понимаю как можно решить. Пробовал  поменять SDK в project settings -> project, менял на corretto-18, kotlin sdk, openjdk-20.

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.8.20
compose.version=1.4.1
```

Так же пробовал заменить на это

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.8.0
compose.version=1.4.1
```

Так же стоит добавить что если захожу в main файл и нажимаю кнопку запуска(зеленая кнпока play), то все работает без ошибок

Comment: Добавьте свой `gradle.properties`, у вас где-то нестыковка между версиями Kotlin/AGP/Compose.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja добавил